# jdbc db2 connection

Tags: jdbc, db2

I'm using Tomcat 7, Eclipse juno, db2 v10.1
i have placed the db2jcc.jar and db2jcc4.cc in the WEB-INF/lib and tommcat library.
I'm getting this error
**java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for dburl,admin123,admin123**
The code i have written is :
 public String execute()

```
    {

        try{
            Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
            String dbURL = "jdbc:db2:localhost:50000/EEMS";
            java.sql.Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("dburl,admin123,admin123");

            String s = "insert into detail values(?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(s);
            ps.setInt(1, beanobject.getAge());
            ps.setString(2, beanobject.getUname());
            ps.setString(3, beanobject.getSex());

            ps.executeUpdate();
            con.commit();

                ps.close();
                con.close();

                    }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                    return SUCCESS;


    }
```

Please Help!!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get a connection for the URL `"dburl,admin123,admin123"`.

Change

```
DriverManager.getConnection("dburl,admin123,admin123");
```

to

```
DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, "admin123", "admin123");
```

And learn more about JDBC: connections should always be closed in a finally block, and you should use a connection pool (and thus a DataSource) to get connections.